# jQuery setInterval() Function - How to shorten the first/onset loop

Tags: jquery

I am using the setInterval function to create a loop with a Text Slider animation:

SEE [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FV5jL/19/)

HTML:

```
<div id="Slider">
<ul>
    <li class="active">Semper Fidelis</li>
    <li>Amat Victoria Curam</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#Slider{
    position: relative;
    left: 50px;
}
#Slider ul{
    list-style: none;
}
#Slider ul li{
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
    line-height: 0px;
}
```

JS:

```
setInterval(function(){
    var $current = $('#Slider ul li.active').animate({'top': '50px'},800)
    .delay(2000).animate({'top': '50px'},800)
    .animate({'top':'-100px'},500)
    .removeClass('active');
    
    if($current.next('li').length > 0) {
        $current.next('li').addClass('active');
    } else {
        $current.siblings('li:eq(0)').addClass('active');
    }
}, 5000);
```

Nowas you can see, the function takes 5000ms to start...Now this is great for the 2nd to nth loop, but I want the first run to begin earlier, say 1000ms and not 5000, while still keeping the pause between loops 5000ms...

How do I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be done like this, using a `setTimeout()` for the initial launch, and then `setInterval` to handle each recurring run.

```
function myAnimation(){
    var $current = $('#Slider ul li.active').animate({'top': '50px'},800)
    .delay(2000).animate({'top': '50px'},800)
    .animate({'top':'-100px'},500)
    .removeClass('active');

    if($current.next('li').length > 0) {
        $current.next('li').addClass('active');
    } else {
        $current.siblings('li:eq(0)').addClass('active');
    }
}

setTimeout(function(){
    myAnimation();
    setInterval(myAnimation, 5000);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I think you forgot a `myAnimation();` before the `setInterval`, or it won't do anything differently than the question apart from delaying the first one another second.

Answer (score 0):

Just put your code in a function and call that function seperately

```
var animate = function () {
    var $current = $('#Slider ul li.active').animate({'top': '50px'},800)
    .delay(2000).animate({'top': '50px'},800)
    .animate({'top':'-100px'},500)
    .removeClass('active');

    if($current.next('li').length > 0) {
        $current.next('li').addClass('active');
    } else { 
        $current.siblings('li:eq(0)').addClass('active');
    }
};

setTimeout(function () {
    animate();
    setInterval(animate, 5000);
}, 1000);
```